# GPIO random input, Difference between scripts?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

So I am currently working on a Raspberry Pi Project.
My Raspi is connected to my letterbox, so everytime someone opens it, a button is pushed. When the button is pushed, a script should detect this and send me an EMail, and write the current Time and Date in a .txt file.

My script that I made a little bit by my self and with the help of the internet, works, but it randomly detects a GPIO input every 10-20 Minutes (the Wires that are connected to the button are very long and my Raspi is connected in a room that is full with cabels, this might be the Problem). But, I tried to do it with a script that I just found on the internet. Just copy it (well, at least the GPIO part). So this script works, but mine detects a random input.

Another Problem (you'll see it in the script) that I had with an old script was, that I used a while loop, and it used 97% of my CPU. So I did another script that would work differently. It doesnt use 97% of my CPU, but it detects random Inputs. In the script that I copied from the internet also uses a while loop, but it doesnt take that much CPU. But why? I dont understand that  either.

This is my Script, that detects random Inputs:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import smtplib
import pytz
from pytz import timezone
import datetime
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.IN,)

def writeanemail(): 

    smtpUser = ''
    smtpPass = ''
    toAdd = ''
    fromAdd = smtpUser
    subject = 'Du hast etwas in deinem Postfach'
    header = 'To:  ' + toAdd + '\n' + 'From:  ' + fromAdd + '\n' + 'Subject:  ' + subject
    print ("\n" + header)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    s.login(smtpUser, smtpPass)
    s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header)
    s.quit()

def timelog():
    now = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
    file = open("/home/pi/ps/gpio.log","a")
    file.write("\n" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%a  %H:%M:%S"))
    file.close()
    print ("\n" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%a  %H:%M") + "\n" + "\n" + "Log wurde geschrieben")

def main():
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(7, GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime = 150)
    print ("Knopf wurde gedrueckt, E-Mail wird geschickt.")
    sleep(1)
    writeanemail()
    timelog()
    sleep(10)
    main()

main()
```

And this is the copied one, that works fine:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from pytz import timezone
import datetime

# SET GPIO Button-Pin
gpio = 7

def writeanemail():
    smtpUser = ''
    smtpPass = ''

    toAdd = ''
    fromAdd = smtpUser

    subject = 'Du hast etwas in deinem Postfach'
    header = 'To:  ' + toAdd + '\n' + 'From:  ' + fromAdd + '\n' + 'Subject:  ' + subject


    print ("\n" + header)

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    s.login(smtpUser, smtpPass)
    s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header)
    s.quit()



 # Main Function
def main():
    value = 0

    while True:
        if not GPIO.input(gpio):
        value += 0.01
        if value > 0:
            if GPIO.input(gpio):
                print "gedrueckt"
                now = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
                file = open("/home/pi/ps/gpio.log","a")
                file.write("\n" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%a  %H:%M:%S"))
                file.close()
                writeanemail()
                main()

        time.sleep(0.03)

  return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
  GPIO.setup(gpio, GPIO.IN)
  main()
```

Here I copied only the main function, the Email part is the same.
I am thankful for any help and advice.